# how to output a value from Array of classes in C#

Tags: arrays

I am trying to display a value from an Array of classes as follows:

```
class Person
{
    private int age;
    private string name;

    public Person(string Name, int Age)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.age = Age;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("No. of family members: ");
        int NoOfEntities = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Person[] people = new Person[NoOfEntities];

        for (int person = 0; person < people.Length; person++)
        {
            Console.Write($"\nName of No. {person + 1} member: ");
            string Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write($"\nAge of No. {person + 1} member: ");
            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            people[person] = new Person(Name, Age);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(people[0].Age);
    }
}
```

but the compiler complains that 'Person' does not contain a definition for 'Age'. All of the examples I found on internet are using the same method to iterate over the array members. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: everything works as intended until I try to output people[i].Name (or Age)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'Person' class, you have defined `age` and `name` as private fields, so they are not accessible from outside of the class (that is why you getting the compiler error). Also note that C# is case sensitive, so `age` is not the same as `Age`.

In C# it is common to use public properties for data. It is also common to use names that start with lower case letters for function parameters and local variables. So you probably want your `Person` class to look like this:

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```